# GooglePlacesAPI no longer showing author_name and profile_photo_url

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I use GooglePlacesAPI and jQuery to output Google Reviews for a business based on Google Place ID. Two variables are no longer outputting data.

`author_name` is no longer outputting username, instead of usernames all reviews show they are from "A Google User"

`profile_photo_url` is no longer outputting user photo, it returns empty.

Both `author_name` and `profile_photo_url` are documented on Google Place Details (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)

The review body and stars still outputs correctly.

Is there another way to call this data?

EDIT: this issue was due to a bug in Google Places API that has now been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been acknowledged as a bug in the Google Advertisers Community by Google. See my response on a related issue:
[Google Place API author_name Anonymous Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189632/google-place-api-author-name-anonymous-problem/52191662#52191662)

Answer (score 0):

while there is an `author_url` ...eg. the one from the example:

https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews

then this can be transformed into a G+ profile with ID `106422854611155436041`:

https://plus.google.com/106422854611155436041

... which can be resolved through the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js) (requires login).

Comment: To confirm, are you saying that I will need to add the People API to my project and rewrite variables to pull data from G+ profile?

Comment: author_url does not exist in the response and it seems that there is no way to get user's name. I believe Google has removed that. Very frustrating. :(

Comment: @SBWT not from the profile, obviously from the People API. @Alex it exists in the `reviews`, most likely only in case the author has a G+ profile (a Gmail account may only have data for the own contacts). don't have a working People API client at hand, but will check out this later/tomorrow.