# Google Place API author_name Anonymous Problem

Tags: google-places-api, anonymous, author

Just notice Google Place API has this update, the problem is all of the names are changed to `A Google user` and it looks like including people is not posted by anonymous:

```
author_name the name of the user who submitted the review.
Anonymous reviews are attributed to "A Google user".
```

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults

I am using a simple JS plugin to display reviews on a website, right now all of the Review author names are changed to `A Google user`: https://github.com/peledies/google-places

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1ta6ekc2/14/, and I try to change a lot of places which the author name is still the same.

From a normal search popup review page, all of those review author names are fine: https://www.google.ca/search?ei=JwKQW-3zB4i6tQXSpZjwBg&q=citizenM+New+York+Times+Square+Hotel&oq=citizenM+New+York+Times+Square+Hotel&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3952.3952.0.4677.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.2.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.3si1JLloRdA#lrd=0x89c258564165b30f:0xdebbed18bae58050,1,,,

Is that a bug or just a new rollout feature from Google? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be fixed. Issue is not reproducible now.

Comment: Yes! They fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been acknowledged as a bug in the Google Advertiser Community here:
https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Basics-for-Business-Owners/name-of-reviewer-Not-Showing/td-p/1797837#.W5Aiz-hxgeA.gmail